# ngFor inside StackLayout is displayed as last component after building apk

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have a small view with a `StackLayout`. When using `tns preview` the components inside are displayed as expected in the order specified. However, when using the apk, the `CheckBoxes` are displayed as last component of the `StackLayout`. The reason seems to be the use of `ngFor`.

Here are two screenshots illustrating the issue:

[Correct behavior when using tns preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IyZp.jpg)

[Incorrect behavior when using apk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zqyms.jpg)

Here is my code:

```html
<app-action-bar title="{{getTitle()}} - Lernen"></app-action-bar>

<StackLayout>

    <Label text="{{currentQuestion.question}}" textwrap="true"></Label>

    <CheckBox *ngFor="let answer of this.userAnswers" text="{{answer.answer}}"></CheckBox>

    <Button text="Weiter!"></Button>

    <Button text="Feedback"></Button>

</StackLayout>
```

I would greatly welcome any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a [known issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/2176) which already [has been fixed](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/pull/2258) in later versions.

If for some reason you cannot update your framework version, as a quick fix you can wrap your `*ngFor` into an additional container to preserve ordering. In your case it could look as follows:

```
<StackLayout>
  <Label text="{{currentQuestion.question}}" textwrap="true"></Label>

  <StackLayout>
    <CheckBox *ngFor="let answer of this.userAnswers" text="{{answer.answer}}"></CheckBox>
  </StackLayout>

  <Button text="Weiter!"></Button>
  <Button text="Feedback"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Was fixed in @nativescript/angular 10.1.4 and 10.1.5